# Incoming Mail MS Exchange On Dynamic DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, email

I have managed to setup exchange server in my office. I am going to use sample.com as the domain here.

I am using dynamic dns wich works fine for the web server. But i am getting no emails. Lets say the email i have allowed on Administrator account as demo@sample.com

My domain has a CNAME of exchange.sample.com and MX @ pointing to that CNAME.

My router is forwarding port 25 to the exchange machine and the exchange domain firewall is off.

So what i am lost here is why the CNAME resolves fine to my dynamic ip and the web server works, but the email inbox doesn't recieve mails i send to the demo@sample.com domain.

Exchange 2010

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong. What have you ruled out/tried already?

Comment: I have checked the ports are all open and forwarding. I am wondering it is due to the setup. I have a domain machine that my router forwards port 25 to. The domain then forwards port 25 to a VPS that connects on the domain and has exchange installed.All the ports are open, the exchange cname pings my dynamic dns perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried manually sending an email from a device outside your network?  Manual, as in, telnet to port 25 and start typing the EHLO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO, etc commands

Comment: Ok this is strange. I have an email address i use with a domain hosted on Godaddy, the email doesn't arrive. i send the email from gmail and it does arrive!

Comment: So a basic netwerk connection appears to work. If you open a telnet connection from various machines to port 25 on exchange.sample.com, can a connection be established? Also, have a look at https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/, which is an online tool to perform various connectivity-tests.

Comment: I can telnet to exchange.sample.com on port 25 yes. Shows the exchange server name. What is odd is that email from Gmail comes in ok, but my domain on godaddy not. But i have just noticed godaddy are having issues with SMTP so i will try again once that is fixed

Comment: i managed to get everything working. i am using gmail smtp using a send connector. I do have 1 more question if you could shed some light. It all works, and the name on the email comes through as it is sent on the exchange email account, but the from address shows the gmail one. Any way i can force the send connector to display the email address from the exchange server the mail was sent from?

Answer (score 1):

`MX` records should not return `CNAME` records.  Point your `MX` to the dynamic name and things should work.

DNS tends to be cached so you may loose mail when your IP changes.

Also use your ISPs relay server to send mail if your want reliable outbound delivery.

EDIT: To fix the outbound addess:  You should be authenticating to GMAIL to forward the email.  Try using the GMAIL address in a `Sender` header, and the desired address in the `From` header.  Alternatively, add a `Repy-to` header with the desired reply address.  Send yourself a message, and check the headers.  The SMTP RFCs describe the headers which should be easy to understand.

Comment: hi i have setup a send connector and it all works. however, i am using gmail smtp and it shows the email that it sent from as my gmail one, rather than the actual email address that is used for the mailbox. Is there a way to make the send connector display the email from the mailbox on the recieving end? Its no good someone replying to the gmail account.

Comment: @NibbrWebDevelopment I've added a couple of likely solutions.  Getting a paid Google account may also solve the issue.  A fixed IP addresses and full email server is another option.

Comment: hi, i know all about headers im a web developer so i use it all the time. However, where do i set up the headers in the exchange management console? or a tutorial if you know of one?

Comment: @NibbrWebDevelopment Normally, the header would be set by the client. In the case of a web application, the application would set the headers.  I don't use Exchange, and I don't know its ability to modify headers.  The Linux/UNIX mail servers can usually do this fairly easily.

Comment: maybe an idea to use linux then im a lot more familiar with linux than windows server. thanks you all your comments its been very helpful